# Axios unable to fetch API data after deploying the React App on firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

I am making an web app to get latest news updates andI am having problem after deploying it. The app is running perfectly on localhost and fetching all data from newsapi but when I deploy it on firebase or github, axios is unable to fetch api or display it on screen. here is [link](https://github.com/ac12644/news-web) to my github repository.

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect } from "react";
import NewsArt from "../NewsArt";
import axios from "axios";



function AllNews(props) {
  

  const [data, setData] = useState({ articles: [] });
 
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await axios(
        'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=09a334ba3fbe41acaff79515476dc4cc',
      );
 
      setData(result.data);
    };
 
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
   
    <div>
      <ul>
      {data.articles.map(item => (
              <NewsArt 
               title= {item.title}
               urlToImage = {item.urlToImage}
               description = {item.description}
               url = {item.url} 
               publishedAt = {item.publishedAt} 
               author = {item.author} />

            ))}

            </ul>
         
    </div>

  );
}

export default AllNews;
```

mgur.com/vltyv.png

Comment: I think the api doesnt work due to CORS. Can you check it on browser inspect?

Comment: [link](https://ac12644.github.io/news-web/) I think so can you please tell me how to make it work?

Comment: Do you use free plan of news api?

Comment: I answered, please let me know your feedback

Comment: Thanks for your check. Please upvote myanswer if you think it works. thanks.

Comment: NEWS API gives you the Developer Plan in the first step if you want to deploy the project then purchase other plan they offered you to publish your app with CORS so don't worry i have also encountered the same problem but at last i also left it where it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]
As you can see here you are using news api as developer plan.
You can see https://newsapi.org/pricing and know CORS is not enabled on deployed site, only enabled on localhost if you are using developer plan.

So two ways to fix this.

- You buy package rather than developer plan to simply use newsapi on your frontend.
- If you dont want to purchase then think about using a backend. I had the same problem and the easiest way around it was making a firebase cloud function which calls news api there and returns customized result which you will use on frontend.